# How can I get the selected time from 2 time tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to get all the data from selected time by the user. For example, I select **10:00 AM** and I have 2 tables (start_shift and end_shift).

start_shift - 9:00 AM (VARCHAR)

end_shift - 12:30 PM (VARCHAR)

This is my Query

```
SELECT * FROM `users` tbl1 LEFT JOIN user_sched tbl2
ON tbl1.uid=tbl2.uid AND TIME(tbl2.start_shift) > TIME('10:00 AM') AND 
TIME(tbl2.end_shift) < TIME('10:00 AM')
WHERE tbl2.sched_day = 'monday'
GROUP BY tbl1.uid
```

Still getting me empty value

```
Users Table
uid | fname  | lname
1   | Robert | Downy
2   | Jorge  | Dee

User Sched Table
sid | sched_day| start_shift | end_shift | uid
1   | monday   | 09:00 AM    | 12:30 PM  | 1
2   | monday   | 01:30 PM    | 05:30 PM  | 2
```

Comment: Can you post your database schema, and sample data?

Comment: `tbl2.uid` should be `tbl2.sid`. Also, no values match your query.

Comment: avoid use `*` that's not good base practice it would be better take column what you need..

Comment: Why do you have 2 time tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think MySQL pays attention to the "AM".  More importantly, your conditions are in the wrong direction.  I think you intend:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     user_sched us
     ON u.uid = us.uid AND
        TIME(us.start_shift) < TIME('10:00:00') AND 
        TIME(us.end_shift) > TIME('10:00:00') AND
        us.sched_day = 'monday';
```

`GROUP BY` with `SELECT *` just does not make sense.  If you are aggregating the rows, normally you would use aggregation functions.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! I just change now the data type of start and end shift to TIME and I don't have an idea that MYSQL doesn't read AM or PM.